# Apache Hangs, Needs restart to recover

Tags: angular, apache

I've been looking at this issue with our Apache Proxy, and can't figure out what is wrong. When problem occurs, it takes forever to load the index.html page. Apache's status looks like below, when there is issue. It shows a lot of slots in Reading state. When it works, it doesn't show that many Reading slots. The problem would go away if we restart Apache, but would return after a few days. The slots with Reading state are all serving request to our entry index.html page. Index.html is a static page in a local directory, served by a VirtualHost. We are using Apache 2.4.46 on Windows. Do we run into some limit on reading files from directory, file handles for example?

Apache's status when it has issue:

```
Server Version: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1h

Server MPM: WinNT

Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Oct 2 2020 11:45:39

Current Time: Tuesday, 12-Jan-2021 16:02:53 Eastern Standard Time

Restart Time: Friday, 08-Jan-2021 16:54:40 Eastern Standard Time

Parent Server Config. Generation: 1

Parent Server MPM Generation: 0

Server uptime: 3 days 23 hours 8 minutes 13 seconds

Server load: -1.00 -1.00 -1.00

Total accesses: 1073057 - Total Traffic: 23.4 GB - Total Duration: 525457491
3.13 requests/sec - 71.8 kB/second - 22.9 kB/request - 489.683 ms/request
332 requests currently being processed, 668 idle workers
________________________________________________________________
________________________________________________________________
________________________________________________________________
________________________________________________________________
________________________________________________________________
________________________________________________________________
________________________________________________________________
________________________________________________________________
______________________R_RRRRRRRRRRRR_RRRRRRRKC_RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RKKRRRRRRRRKRRRRRRRRRRRC_RRRRRRK_R__R_RKKRRR______R_R_K_________
_________R_______________R_______R_R_R___R__RRK_RKRRRRRRRRRRKR_R
RR_R_RR_RRR_R_K_RRW_C__W__R_RRRRR_____RC_R_R_WRRRRRRW__RRRR___R_
RRRR_RRRRRKRRRRKRR_RRR_RR_KRRCRR__R_RRRRRRRRRR__RRRR_RRR_R_RRRR_
C_RRRRR_RR_RRRRRRRK_RR___RRRRRR__R_RKKRRRR__RR_KRRRR_RRRRRRRRR_R
_RRRRRRRRKKRRRKRR_R_RRRRRRRRKR_RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR_RR__RRRRKR_RRRRR
R_RRRRRRKRRR_WRRRRRRRKR_RR_R_R_RRRRRK_CR

Scoreboard Key:
"_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
"W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
"C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
"I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process
```

Comment: It might be because of your RAM usage. Check you RAM usage.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. RAM util is less than 45% for the entire OS normally, but I will look at that metric when it starts to become unresponsive.

Comment: let me know if the RAM bumps up when apache hangs

Comment: Did this start happening just under a week ago by any chance?

Comment: @Moshezauros, no, it happened more than a week ago, maybe 2 or 3 months, possibly happened after we added a virtualhost for an Angular app.

Comment: we have a similar issue, if we solve it, I'll post here

Comment: @Moshezauros, I read somewhere that reducing Timeout may help getting rid of stuck Reading connections sooner. Our Timeout is current set to 300 seconds, I'll reduce that to something like 15 seconds and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by enabling HTTP/2 on our Apache. HTTP/2 wasn't enabled by default, so we've been using just HTTP/1.1. I also converted all domains to HTTPS as HTTP doesn't actually use HTTP/2 protocol. We decided to make these changes after observing that Chrome opens a lot of speculative connections and keeps them in Reading state which eventually makes Apache hang. HTTP/2 protocol would help cleaning them up with its Goaway frame.

Comment: I also have the problem. After upgrade to http/2 , everything seems working fine. Thanks for the solution.